# Is $g(x)$ an asymptote of function $f(x)= \sqrt[3]{x^3 -4x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Analyzing funtion $f(x)= \sqrt[3]{x^3 -4x}\;$,
since $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x) = +\infty$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x) = -\infty$, I concluded that there are no asymptotes.

I also found that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x} = 1 $, so there is function $g(x)= x$.

**Is function $g(x)$ an asymptote of function $f(x)$?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

From wiki: In analytic geometry, an asymptote (/ˈæsɪmptoʊt/) of a curve is a line such that the distance between the curve and the line approaches zero as one or both of the x or y coordinates tends to infinity.

It is clear that $f(x)$ approaches the line $g(x)$ as $x$ goes towards $\pm\infty$.